I can't make collisions work in p5js with circles
I have followed the instructions of a "TheCodingTrain" tutorial, it describes how to calculate the distance between two circles to emulate collisions. I have a lot more, but this is the code I have pertaining to my problem.
  playerPos = createVector(width * 0.2, height / 2, 60);
  enemyPos1 = createVector(width * 0.8, height / 2, 40);

  d = dist(playerPos.x,playerPos.y,enemyPos1.x,enemyPos1.y);

  circle(playerPos.x, playerPos.y, playerPos.z);
  circle(enemyPos1.x, enemyPos1.y, enemyPos1.z);

  if( d < playerPos.z/2 + enemyPos1.z/2){
     enemyPos1.x++
  }

I tried the code above, it did not make the position of the smaller circle change. I was expecting it to move. I have gone through and I haven't identified any problems with the code.

is d < playerPos.z/2 + enemyPos1.z/2 ?

Is this code inside the draw() function? Changing the enemyPos1 position won't affect the position if you overwrite it in the next cycle anyway with 'createVector'.

You don't have any code to create movement. You have two circles which don't overlap, and aren't moving so will not overlap. Generally one uses a velocity vector that is added to the position to create movement. Then, when the circles actually overlap, your collision detection code will work:
let playerPos, enemyPos1;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  playerPos = createVector(width * 0.2, height / 2, 60);
  enemyPos1 = createVector(width * 0.8, height / 2, 40);
  playerSpd = createVector(1, 0, 0);
  enemySpd1 = createVector(-1,0,0);
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  d = dist(playerPos.x, playerPos.y, enemyPos1.x, enemyPos1.y);

  circle(playerPos.x, playerPos.y, playerPos.z);
  circle(enemyPos1.x, enemyPos1.y, enemyPos1.z);

  if (d < playerPos.z / 2 + enemyPos1.z / 2) {
    console.log("hit");
  }
  
  playerPos = playerPos.add(playerSpd);
  enemyPos1 = enemyPos1.add(enemySpd1);
}

